# Circle Select permanently selected

Tags: selection-tools, object-mode

I am a Blender newbie and just can't get ahead now. Unfortunately I somehow selected the Circle Select and now I can't get it to go away. I have already tried any buttons but I can not get it back Box Select.
I hope you know a way...
have Blender 3.3.1 if that helps....

Comment: Did you pressed `C` on your keyboard?

Comment: Yes... but it did not work...I reset all my settings and even that did not work

Comment: Did you try the <kbd>W</kbd> key? It should cycle through all of the selection tools.

Comment: Press Escape key?

Comment: I tried all these button combinations. In the select button box it also switches to the other tool, but as soon as I click on the object, it automatically switches back to Circle Select. I also already feel very stupid, but as I said even resetting the settings does not work